# Angular JS sample projects

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angular JS through some tutorials and was looking for sample  project on codeplex/github.I would appreciate if someone can point  me to some link/sample application to get hands on Angular application.

Comment: no a proper question but heres my github account theres 2 project that use angular in there https://github.com/joeLloyd/Scripto5000 https://github.com/joeLloyd/MEANStack

Comment: This repo has a collection of PDF , tutorilas and article links about angular. https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning

Comment: Thanks Joe and Shaoha for the links and guys please specify reason before down voting when you know  something don't expect everyone at same level you need to growup..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try these links for some samples -

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Projects-using-AngularJS

http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/learn-angularjs-5-examples/

http://www.angularcode.com